# Dell Precision M4300 Lock 9 Character

Tags: keyboard, lock, dell-precision

What does it mean when character that looks like a Lock with a 9 in it on the upper part of the Dell Precision M4300 keyboard lights up?

Comment: It sounds like Num lock to me.

Answer (score 1):

It’s [Num Lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Num_lock). When activated, your number pad is a number pad and can type numbers; otherwise it acts as arrow keys and some other functions.